# 2007 Suzuki Forenza motor

Tags: engine, suzuki

I took my 2007 Suzuki Forenza in for regular maintenance to replace timing belt, nothing was wrong with it. I was just following suggested time to change. They changed it and the water pump, but put belt on too loose and it edged around one of the pulleys and melted it off and ruined the engine. They replaced engine w/ a used engine at their cost and put a new belt one...however, it was misfiring and leaking oil and getting really hot, so I took it back and they said it needed a new valve cover bc they think it was cracked??? so then it continued leaking oil and sucking the radiator run off tank dry constantly. A friend of mine who is a mechanic said it looks to be a warped head and it would constantly need a new valve covers and he said it is a bad engine and needs to be replaced. So, I took it back and they replaced the valve cover again and said it is fine. However it is overheating and smoking heavily...I just do not think it is safe to drive. I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Tell them to put a new engine in it again. If that doesn't work, hire an attorney to tell them to do it. Usually, when an attorney gets involved, people start jumping through their butts.

Comment: @Paulster2   you said "jumping through their butts."